Should I say "n remaining" or "remaining n"
Let's say I have 52 playing cards and I deal out 12 of them. How do I properly refer to the other 40 cards? For example:

Now choose from the 40 remaining cards

or

Now choose from the remaining 40 cards

How about when the word "cards" isn't present? For example

Of the 40 remaining, 10 of them are...

or

Of the remaining 40, 10 of them are...


Are you asking if one is right and the other wrong, or if one option is simply used more than the other?

Um. I guess I'm asking the first of your questions; and then if the answer is that they're both correct, I'm asking the second

The question of acceptability is certainly answered (by ghoppe) at Can participial adjectives be placed without a noun after them?. 'Participle adjectives can go after the noun. Be aware that the placement may change the meaning....
There are a handful of adjectives that can go before or after the noun, like stolen or remaining. [no change in meaning]
The stolen paintings were worth six million dollars.
The paintings stolen were worth six million dollars.'

10 of them are what? Not choosable? :)

Play around with this ngram, maybe.

Both forms are perfectly valid, but English normally puts the adjective before the noun, as reflected by this usage chart...


Similarly with 'six' / 'ten' / 'thirty'.

Actually, after posting this I realised I might not be comparing like with like, because my chart doesn't include a specific noun such as cards. The most common explicitly-specified noun seems to be members, and with that included, both forms are equally common. But in the OP's context you probably wouldn't want to keep repeating the word cards anyway. Just the number itself is a perfectly good identifier in context.

Thanks, this is how I did it most often anyway (I just realised I'd been using both orders in my writing). I'm working on a document talking through the maths of the probability of poker hands. When figuring out how many ways there are to make a hand, you need to 'choose' cards. For example: A five-card royal flush can be turned into a seven-card royal flush by simply choosing two additional cards from the remaining 47 cards... and However, of the remaining 47, there is...

I think the only case where I have n remaining is when I haven't preceeded it by the word the, for example flushes only occur when all three remaining cards are of this suit. Does this seem like a sensible approach?

For most purposes it doesn't make any difference whether you put remaining before or after the noun. But noting @EdwinAshworth's comment under the question, I'd say there could be a significant difference of nuance between #1: The stolen paintings were worth six million dollars and #2: The paintings stolen were worth six million dollars. To my mind, #1 is the natural form. Note that "adjective first" still works with His damaged car wasn't worth much, whereas His car damaged wasn't worth much is completely unacceptable to me. BUT...

...#2: The paintings stolen were worth six million dollars is at least slightly "marked". And to my mind, it strongly implies that there were other paintings that weren't stolen, whereas #1 implies nothing about whether any other paintings even existed. I'd parse #2 as "reduced" from The paintings that were stolen were worth...

Good example. 'The stolen paintings were worth six million dollars.' / 'The paintings stolen were worth six million dollars.' may or may not carry the same sense, imo. The first 'stolen' may refer to the state of the paintings, or, like 'The paintings stolen', more to the theft.

Either is fine. If you are going to make several references to the set of forty remaining cards, you can create the idea that you want to treat the set of forty as a unit by putting forty with cards. If you want to concentrate on the idea that the resulting remainder is the item of interest, then use remaining cards. It's easier to parse later instances that way.
So if the operation is to remove further cards, I would tend to use forty remaining cards, resulting in fewer remaining cards. If the operation is to describe the set, I would probably reverse this and talk about the remaining forty cards, because the idea of remaining quickly becomes unnecessary.
